# New repo with same name - how to reset my git CLI and upload code?

Tags: git, github, version-control, command-line-interface

I have a new repo that takes over the repo name of another repo, whose name I changed and which I am keeping for backup.

I used to upload code to the repo with the following code

```
git add .
git commit -m 'some title'
git push -u origin master
```

And it would work. For the newly-created repo (which has taken over the old repo's name), I tried following the steps that you get when you create a new repo:

```
echo "# goodgrowth" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
git push -u origin main
```

But it took all the code and branches from my previous project and added them to the newly created repo.

How can I start from scratch on my new repo and what do I need to upload the code (first time and afterwards)?

Last time I puzzled around with git commands I found on the internet, the command went into my local files and reverted a day of work, didn't even know that was possible for a command to do. Not going that route again...

Comment: All I'm going to say here is that you would be better off giving a new and different repository a new and different name.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I start from scratch on my new repo and what do I need to upload the code (first time and afterwards)?

If you don't need the history of the previous repository, you can:

- clone the new (empty) one
- copy the files from the old one
- add, commit, and push

Comment: Hi Vonc, I am not looking to keep the old files from the old one. I have everything in my local directory so can just upload that. What are the steps for that, if I may ask?

Comment: @beyondtdr Since the push did not work correctly, I would do the same step as in the answer, except I would copy my current file (in the local directory) to the cloned (empty) repository.